# selecting multiple values from a dictionary to calulate the average of them

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

hi all i am currently struggling with selecting multiple values/keys from a dictionary

below is my code

```
test = {
    "name": "test",
    "a": [50,60,80,90], 
    "b": [40,68,67,89],
    "c": [44,55,67,78] 
    }

for k, v in test.items():
    print(k, v)

for k, v in test.items():
    if k == 'a, b, c':
        number_list = v
        avg = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
        print("The average for test total is ", round(avg,2))
```

when i run this it doesn't show the average for all three keys/values

but when i run

```
for k, v in test.items():
    if k == 'a':
        number_list = v
        avg = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
        print("The average for test a is ", round(avg,2))
```

it prints key/value 'a'

i have tried the following:

```
for k, v in test.items():
    if k == 'a' and 'b' and 'c':
        number_list = v
        avg = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
        print("The average for test total is ", round(avg,2))
```

^
when i run this it only prints 'a' it does take 'b' or 'c' into account

```
for k, v in test.items():
    if k == 'a' + 'b' + 'c':
        number_list = v
        avg = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
        print("The average for test total is ", round(avg,2))
```

^
this is the same as my current code where it doesn't show up when i run the code

```
for k, v in test.items():
    if k == 'a', 'b', 'c':
        number_list = v
        avg = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
        print("The average for test total is ", round(avg,2))
```

^
comes up as an invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `in` operator and place the values in the list.

```
test = {
    "name": "test",
    "a": [50,60,80,90], 
    "b": [40,68,67,89],
    "c": [44,55,67,78] 
    }

for k, v in test.items():
    print(k, v)

for k, v in test.items():
    if k in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        number_list = v
        avg = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
        print("The average for test total is ", round(avg,2))
```

`Case 1-`

`k == 'a, b, c':`  Here, you are checking the k with string 'a,b,c' means you're trying to check if 'a' == 'a,b,c' which is wrong.

`Case 2 -`

`k == 'a' and 'b' and 'c'` Here, you're messing up with  `==`  and `and`. The `==` will 1st check if the key is equal to `a` or not . It means when `k == 'a'` returns True - It'll start to perform `and` operation and the final value will be `c`.

To take total average of all the keys specified in the list -

```
keys_to_use = ['a','b','c']
result = sum(sum(value)/len(value) for key,value in test.items() if key in keys_to_use)/len(keys_to_use)
```

Comment: it worked, im very appreciative of the detail you went into it helped me understand it a lot more. the issue i am getting now is im trying to get it to give me the average for all 3 choices, not them individually

Comment: thank you for the update, is there any particular reason why when i print result it prints it 4 times?

Sorry for all the questions i really do appreciate this

Answer (score 1):

```
test = {
    "name": "test",
    "a": [50,60,80,90], 
    "b": [40,68,67,89],
    "c": [44,55,67,78] 
    }

for k, v in test.items():
    print(k, v)

for k, v in test.items():
    try:
        if k == "a"or "b" or "c":
            avg = sum(v)/len(v)
            print("The average for test total is ", round(avg,2))
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: it worked, thank you, but i was trying to get it so it gave me the average for all 3 choices, not them individually but it gave me a short cut with code and taught me something new